# My BroadcastReceiver won't call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i have a problem for calling my BroadcastReceiver.i don't know wehere the issue is.
here is my code Myalarm.class who call automatically the BroadcastReceiver(AlarmReceiver) .
i did some TAG in Broadcast to see if he called..then i figured out that the boradcast won't call

MyAlarm.class

```
public class MyAlarm extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 42;
    private String notificationTitle;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    String ID_Alerte;
    long alarm_GPS;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myalarm);
        ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.annuler)).setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle myBundle= i.getExtras();
        alarm_GPS = myBundle.getLong("alarm_gps");
        ID_Alerte = myBundle.getString("id_alerte"); 
        //  openTimePickerDialog(false);

        ///////////// call AlarmReceiver//////////////:
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentlocalisation = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        //put data to BroadcastReceiver 
        intentlocalisation.putExtra("id_alerte", ID_Alerte);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentlocalisation, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+3000, alarm_GPS , pi); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.annuler:
        /////////   Alarm SMS cancel (AlarmReceiver)  //////////
            Intent intent_stopsms = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent sendersms = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent_stopsms, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManagersms = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManagersms.cancel(sendersms);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled alarm sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent adv=new Intent(MyAlarm.this,
                    Home.class);
            startActivity(adv);
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String ID_Alerte;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        arg0.stopService(new Intent(arg0, MyService.class));
        ///////////////////////////
        Log.i("Alarm Receiver","My receive is shown up");
        ID_Alerte=arg1.getStringExtra("id_alerte");
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!id_alerte=" +ID_Alerte , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //////////////////////////////////
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(arg0,MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("id_alerte", ID_Alerte);
        arg0.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

and this is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SherlockCustom" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.my_app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MonProfile" />
        <activity android:name=".Register" />
        <activity android:name=".Home" />
        <activity android:name=".Home1" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity3" />
        <activity android:name=".MyAlarm" />
        <activity android:name=".JSONParsingAlertes" />
        <activity android:name=".JSONParsingProches" />
        <activity android:name=".Profil_Proche" />
        <activity android:name=".Nouveau_Proche" />
        <activity android:name=".Modifier_Proche" />
        <activity android:name=".detailAlert" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Code_Request" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentification"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Advanced"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Tracer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".LegalNoticesActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityNotification"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <service android:name=".NotificationService" />
        <service android:name=".GetProche" />
        <service android:name=".MyService" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.my_app.AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="true" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*************************" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.my_app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

</manifest>
```

PS: sorry if my engish is not well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it doesn't work because of your receiver declaration which is missing the `intent-filter` section:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.my_app.AlarmReceiver">
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.example.my_app.MyAlarm.FIRE_ALARM" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And then of course you have to set the action for your intent in your `MyAlarm` class via `intent.setAction("com.example.my_app.MyAlarm.FIRE_ALARM")`. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

```
 ///////////// call AlarmReceiver//////////////:
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentlocalisation = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    //put data to BroadcastReceiver 
    intentlocalisation.putExtra("id_alerte", ID_Alerte);
    Intentlocalisation.setAction("com.example.my_app.MyAlarm.FIRE_ALARM")        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentlocalisation, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+3000, alarm_GPS , pi); 

}
```

Comment: sorry but i don't know what should i do in setAction() to call AlarmReceiver periodically.

PS: i only added that intent-filter in my manifest..but style don't work